# How to extract from a multi-indexed pandas.Series object based on secondary level criterion?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a pandas DataFrame sample object below on which I perform a group-by correlation calculation.  At the end I would like to view the time-series correlation between `Value1` and `Value2`

```
data = [
(1, 'alpha', 3, 101, 2),
(1, 'beta', 2, 102, 3),
(1, 'gamma', 5, 103, 4),
(2, 'alpha', 2.5, 101, 1),
(2, 'beta', 2.2, 105, 2),
(2, 'gamma', 5, 100, 0),
(3, 'alpha', 2.1, 102, 0),
(3, 'beta', 2.0, 102, 3.3),
(3, 'gamma', 5, 100, 2),
]

datapd = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=('Time', 'ID', 'Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3'))
corrvals = datapd.groupby('Time').corr()
```

So when I look at `corrvals['Value1']`, I would like to only select all the `Value2` items.  However they're on a level after `Time`.  E.g. `corrvals['Value1'].index.values` shows:

```
array([(1, 'Value1'), (1, 'Value2'), (1, 'Value3'), (2, 'Value1'),
       (2, 'Value2'), (2, 'Value3'), (3, 'Value1'), (3, 'Value2'),
       (3, 'Value3')], dtype=object)
```

How do I ask for all the values with the index `Value2` in the 2nd tuple and no requirements on the first?

Comment: Is this something you are looking for `corrvals.Value1[:,'Value2']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the new [`IndexSlice`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
In [17]:
idx = pd.IndexSlice
corrvals.loc[idx[:,'Value2']]

Out[17]:
Time        
1     Value1    0.654654
      Value2    1.000000
      Value3    1.000000
2     Value1   -0.725288
      Value2    1.000000
      Value3    0.944911
3     Value1   -0.999569
      Value2    1.000000
      Value3   -0.121560
Name: Value2, dtype: float64
```

or `Slice`:

```
In [18]:
corrvals.loc[slice(None),'Value2']

Out[18]:
Time        
1     Value1    0.654654
      Value2    1.000000
      Value3    1.000000
2     Value1   -0.725288
      Value2    1.000000
      Value3    0.944911
3     Value1   -0.999569
      Value2    1.000000
      Value3   -0.121560
Name: Value2, dtype: float64
```

Or pass `axis=0` to `loc`:

```
In [19]:
corrvals.loc(axis=0)[:,'Value2']

Out[19]:
               Value1  Value2    Value3
Time                                   
1    Value2  0.654654       1  1.000000
2    Value2 -0.725288       1  0.944911
3    Value2 -0.999569       1 -0.121560
```

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to point out this warning [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers) for the reason you have different results between:

```
In [13]: idx = pd.IndexSlice
```

This selects on the COLUMNS. as this is EXACTLY the same as `corrvals.loc[:,'Value2']`, e.g. typical column selection

```
In [15]: corrvals.loc[idx[:,'Value2']]
Out[15]: 
Time        
1     Value1    0.654654
      Value2    1.000000
      Value3    1.000000
2     Value1   -0.725288
      Value2    1.000000
      Value3    0.944911
3     Value1   -0.999569
      Value2    1.000000
      Value3   -0.121560
Name: Value2, dtype: float64
```

This selects on the INDEX. (notice the trailing commas).

```
In [16]: corrvals.loc[idx[:,'Value2'],]
Out[16]: 
               Value1  Value2    Value3
Time                                   
1    Value2  0.654654       1  1.000000
2    Value2 -0.725288       1  0.944911
3    Value2 -0.999569       1 -0.121560
```

Finally, here is another way to do this selection, using `.query`. The `ilevel_1` is a moniker for the 1st level (these are numbered starting at 0), as it doesn't have a name.

```
In [18]: corrvals.index.names
Out[18]: FrozenList([u'Time', None])

In [17]: corrvals.query('ilevel_1=="Value2"')
Out[17]: 
               Value1  Value2    Value3
Time                                   
1    Value2  0.654654       1  1.000000
2    Value2 -0.725288       1  0.944911
3    Value2 -0.999569       1 -0.121560
```

You can rename the levels.

```
In [19]: corrvals.index = corrvals.index.set_names(['Time','Values'])
```

Then the query is simple.

```
In [20]: corrvals.query('Values=="Value2"')
Out[20]: 
               Value1  Value2    Value3
Time Values                            
1    Value2  0.654654       1  1.000000
2    Value2 -0.725288       1  0.944911
3    Value2 -0.999569       1 -0.121560
```

Comment: Thanks for adding this, I did notice this difference in the output but the values were correct so didn't think too deeply about it, this is a good explanation of the semantic differences